# Windows move to different displays and Spaces whenever Mac goes to sleep

Tags: windows, spaces

This is a problem I've experienced in the past, but it seems to have gotten much, much, *much* worse under Monterey. It's a fairly simple problem: Whenever my computer wakes from sleep, none of my windows are in the places I left them. They sometimes move on the display they're supposed to be on, but more often, they move to other Spaces. If it helps, I use two large external displays on a MacBook Pro with the lid closed.

I've tried using Display Maid to save and restore window positions, and while this helps somewhat, it can only restore windows to their previous coordinates on the current screen. It has no knowledge of Spaces whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Comment: Often, this is due to the screens waking up too slowly for the Mac to register them. Workaround is to wake them manually before waking the Mac. [I'm sure there must be a 'smarter' way, but no matter how often this question crops up, I've never known anyone provide one.]

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple questions on Apple's useless support forums that are marked as solved, but are clearly not. I haven't really tested this yet, but I deleted a bunch of preferences (displays, Mission Control, Dock, etc.) and I'm hoping that it improves a bit. I use an app to keep the computer from sleeping, so hopefully it won't be an issue for a while.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have monitors that don't all wake together but I don't have OP's problem.  When the last monitor wakes the windows all go back to where they should be.  Not an answer but hopefully a useful data point.  MBP, two monitors, lid closed, Caldigit dock

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I upgraded my old iMac to the new power book 14" 10 16 core gpu. I set up the panels in indesign as I like to have them then the machine went into sleep mode. Upon awakening the main window was halfway down the screen and the palettes had shifted. Meaning moving them back to where they should be. To cut a long story short I bought a new monitor. The problem disappeared. Its something to do with the monitor and the hertz. My work computer monitor is 60. my new monitor is 75hertz.

Comment: My band-aid solution was to install Amphetamine and just never let the computer sleep. Not ideal, but convenient and effective. I may eventually get a CalDigit Thunderbolt dock, which would let me run both monitors at 60Hz (right now one goes through an Apple multiport adapter so it's limited to HDMI at 30Hz). Based on what you said, that might actually work (plus I want the dock anyway).

Comment: The refresh rate is irrelevant - that is how many times per second your display can refresh the image.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out the monitor Hertz is not the issue. My machine was not in full sleep mode. I used to love apple and adobe products. Now they release without full testing which is very annoying and not acceptable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321881)